# Adding Extra property to CSS External file

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS class in a External file

```
.notification
{
background:lightgreen;
}
```

I am using this css selector all over my application wherever required and I don't want to edit this class as it was provided by **kickstart(ToolKit**).

But I need to add one more property to this css selector. What is the best way to do this?

I was planning like in my external file

```
.notification
{
color:green;
}
```

So now both **background and color** will be applied. Is this is a right way?

I don't want to use inline css.

Comment: Yup, that looks fine!

Comment: If you got any answer, upvote somebody, and mark one answer as the correct answer. This will help other people to save time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same way as you shown in the question to add more properties to the existing style, and more over you can override same css property using `!important`.

Like this:

```
.notification
{
   background:red !important;
   color:green;
}
```

So this will apply `background:red` to the element instead of lightgreen.

Comment: !important is a blunt tool and should only be used as a last resort!

Comment: Anyway !important is important!

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding the

```
.notification
{
color:green;
}
```

bit in your own file, both the `color:red` and `background:lightgreen` styles would be applied. This is because `cascading` is applied to individual style properties and not entire class/id/tag style definitions. Though if you add, say, `background:red` in your own style that would overwrite the externally applied `lightgreen` background.(given their identical specificities)

[Cascading](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html)

[Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. The best one is the one you provide us. by adding the extra feature in a file that loaded in your document next to the primary CSS file.

So lets say tou have the app.css first loaded in your document with the css block:

```
.notification
{
    background:lightgreen;
}
```

then later in your document lets say you load your custom file custom.css. In the custom.css it is legal to do this:

```
.notification
{
    color : green;
}
```

or even

```
.notification
{
    background : blue;
}
```

Another way to get this same effect is by using several other classes as "switches". So in example lets say you have:

```
.greeFonts
{
    color : green;
}

.redFonts
{
    color : red;
}
```

and then in your document you can do something like that:

```
<div class="notification greenFonts">My notification</a>
```

But note, the second solutio cannot update all the pre-defined classes, this is good for new inseted notifications. The second solution is good, for new builded web sites, in case you like to use many styles for the "same" elements